# Restart ORACLE OHAS without restarting databases

Tags: oracle, oracle-grid-control

looks like ohasd is getting to much memory (memory leak or something) that cause heavy swapping, is it possible to restart OHAS (till patch is applied) without bouncing databases?

"crsctl stop has" puts all resources down :(

Comment: Which process? Some of them can be restarted without affecting databases.

Answer (score 1):

No, because the Grid Infrastructure generally controls networking and storage access. If you can't start the DB without starting GI first, then you can't restart GI without restarting the database too.